# How to create inputs that you can keep adding to a collection in meteor

Tags: javascript, list, input, meteor

I am trying to figure out how to create a form that has a input field, as well as a "+" button to add another input field. I than want to take those inputs and insert them into a collection. Than output them as a list. Basically I want to give the option to add as many list items as possible. If there is a better way to do this instead of a "+" button to add input fields,I' open to any suggestions.

code so far

HTML

```
<template name="postsList">

  <div class="posts">
    {{#each posts}}
      {{> postItem}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>

</template>

<template name="postItem">

  <h2>{{service}}</h2>
  <ul><li>{{task}}</li></ul>

</template>


<template name="postSubmit">
  <form>
    <label for="service">Add a Service</label>
    <input name="service" type="text" value="" placeholder="Service Type"/>
    <label for="task">Add a task (spaces between each kind)</label>
    <input name="task" type="text" value="" placeholder="type or task for service"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
'submit form': function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

  var post = {
    service: $(e.target).find('[name=service]').val(),
    task: $(e.target).find('[name=task]').val()
  };


  Meteor.call('post', post, function(error, id) {
    if (error)
      return alert(error.reason);
      Router.go('postPage', {_id: id});
  });
 }
});

Posts = new Meteor.Collection('posts');
Posts.allow({
  update: ownsDocument,
  remove: ownsDocument
});
Posts.deny({
  update: function(userId, post, fieldNames) {
    // may only edit the following two fields:
    return (_.without(fieldNames, 'service', 'task').length > 0);
  }
});

Meteor.methods({
  post: function(postAttributes) {
    var user = Meteor.user(),
      postWithSameLink = Posts.findOne({url: postAttributes.url});

    // ensure the user is logged in
    if (!user)
      throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You need to login to post new stories");

    // ensure the post has a service
    if (!postAttributes.service)
      throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please fill in a service');

    // ensure the post has a task
    if (!postAttributes.task)
      throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'Please fill in a task');

    // check that there are no previous posts with the same link
    if (postAttributes.url && postWithSameLink) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(302,
        'This link has already been posted',
        postWithSameLink._id);
    }

    // pick out the whitelisted keys
    var post = _.extend(_.pick(postAttributes, 'service', 'task'), {
      userId: user._id,
      author: user.username,
      submitted: new Date().getTime()
    });

    var postId = Posts.insert(post);

    return postId;
  }
});

Template.postsList.helpers({
  posts: function() {
    return Posts.find({}, {fields: {service: 1, task: 1}}).map(function(post, index) {
    return post;
    });
  }
});
```